# C -- Inserting string data into linked list crashes program when freeing memory

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

First post on StackOverflow (tester by trade, extremely bad programmer in spare time).  For disclosure purposes, this is a university assignment I'm struggling with (asking questions here isn't forbidden as far as I'm aware.

Anyway, I have a program that reads a line from a text file, tokenises the line data, creates a linked list and then inserts each token (2 strings, 1 float, 1 unsigned) into the node.  All is fine until the memory being used by the node is freed - the entire program crashes.  After debugging, I've seemingly isolated the problem to the two string copy operations.  They both seem perfectly valid, but the free() doesn't like them at all.  Tried strncpy() - no difference.  Tried copying the string char by char - no difference. Now I'm at a loss...

Code below, if anyone would like to take a look (oh, more disclosure - pretty much a complete C n00b, so yes, if you see poor practices below, that would be me...)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ts.h"
int main(void)
{
    /* Variables */
    FILE *stream;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    /* Open stock file */         //TODO - make this dynamic, don't hard-code file name
    stream = fopen("stock.csv", "r");
    assert(stream);
    /* Using addStockNode */
    while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, stream))
    {
        addStockNode(buf);
    }
}
void addStockNode(char* stockLine)
{
    //Create linked list
    StockNodePtr head, new, current, previous, nextStock;
    unsigned listSize;

    char *stkTok1, *stkTok2, *stkTok3, *stkTok4;
    unsigned stkLevel;
    int i;
    float stkPrice;

    listSize = 0;
    head = NULL;

        /* Create new stock node */
        if ((new = malloc(sizeof(StockNodePtr))) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"\nMemory allocation for node insertion failed\n");
            fprintf(stderr,"Aborting\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* Tokenise data */
        stkTok1 = strtok(stockLine, ",");
        stkTok2 = strtok(NULL, ",");
        stkTok3 = strtok(NULL, ",");
        stkTok4 = strtok(NULL, ",");

        /* Search to find where in insert new list node */      //TODO - needs to be adapted to sort by stock DESCRIPTION
        current = head;
        previous = NULL;

        /* stockID */
     // strcpy(new->stockID, stkTok1);                 //falls over at free()
     // strncpy(new->stockID, stkTok1, STOCKID_LEN);   //falls over at free()

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(stkTok1); i++)           //still falls over at free()
        {
            new->stockID[i] = stkTok1[i];
        }

        /* description */
     // strcpy(new->description, stkTok2);              //falls over at free()

        /* unitPrice */
        stkPrice = strtof(stkTok3, NULL);
        new->unitPrice = stkPrice;

        /* StockLevel */
        stkLevel = strtol(stkTok4, NULL, 10);
        new->stockLevel = stkLevel;

        /*nextStock */
        new->nextStock = current;

        /* Increment listSize */
        listSize++;

        //TAKE OUT LATER - loadData can iterate through each line of the file */
        if(previous == NULL)            
        {
            head = new;
        }
        else
        {
            previous->nextStock = new;
        }

    /* Print node details */
    current = head;
    printf("%s,%s,%f,%i\n", current->stockID, current->description, current->unitPrice, current->stockLevel);       

    /* Deallocate memory used by node */
    current = head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        nextStock = current->nextStock;
        free(current);    //EXECUTE THIS, IT FALLS OVER (with strcpy lines uncommented)
        current = nextStock;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}*
```

For completeness purposes, here's the stock node struct...

```
typedef struct stockNode
{
   char stockID[STOCKID_LEN + 1];
   char description[DESCRIPTION_MAX + 1];
   float unitPrice;
   unsigned stockLevel;
   StockNodePtr nextStock;
} StockNodeType;
```

If anyone can point out where I'm going wrong, I'd appreciate it!

Edit - Here are the stock node constants...

```
#define STOCKID_LEN 5
#define DESCRIPTION_MAX 40
#define PRICE_COLWIDTH 7
#define STOCKLEVEL_COLWIDTH 3
#define STOCKLEVEL_MAX 100
```

Oh, and the stock data that's being added (not that there's anything wrong with it)...

```
S0001,Slazenger Classic Racquet,150.00,5
S0002,Slazenger Lite Racquet,98.00,3
S0003,Wilson Tournament Gold Balls,14.95,20
S0004,Dunlop Grand Prix Balls,10.95,25
S0005,Luft Nemesis Racquet,125.00,1
S0006,Wilson Tournament Balls,12.95,12
```

Comment: May as well add a sample set of data from the input file, appended to the question please, not as a comment. Thanks. The values of your constants (BUFSIZ, STOCKID_LEN and DESCRIPTION_MAX) as well, please.

Comment: did you do any protection on link list OP when releasing node?

Comment: @Daniel - sorry, I have no idea what that means (as far as study goes, I've only covered very basic linked list and memory management functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Main Defect


Your fundamental problem is under-allocation, specifically this:

```
if ((new = malloc(sizeof(StockNodePtr))) == NULL)
```

Which means you're allocating space large enough to hold a pointer; not a stock node.

Try this instead:

```
if ((new = malloc(sizeof(*new))) == NULL)
```

Note: I've not thoroughly read the rest of this, but that is pretty huge in itself, as you're never allocating more memory per node than the size of a pointer. If there are other issues, I'll comment as I see them.

---

## General Review

The following a general observations and suggestions within the code body not necessarily related to the main defect. Most of them point out problems that could, however, contribute to future defects.

**Variable Initialization**

Regarding general coding practice. **never** declare an uninitialized pointer. Ideally, never declare uninitialized *anything*. Things like this:

```
StockNodePtr head, new, current, previous, nextStock;
unsigned listSize;
```

can come back to really bite you on the bum. These should be as such:

```
StockNodePtr head=NULL, new=NULL, currentNULL, previousNULL, nextStockNULL;
unsigned listSize = 0;
```

If you're worried about initializing a value only to have it written over immediately after the declaration, fret not. The compiler will optimize that for you (volatile not withstanding).

**Linked List Construction**

A common problem in constructing a tail-appended linked list is knowing where the last "next" pointer is. People often jumble with two or three pointers, special case the head pointer on initial construction etc. I'm here to tell you none of that is needed.

Consider how a dbl-pointer (a pointer that holds the address of another pointer variable) can be *very* effective in assisting a tail-appended list during construction:

```
StockNodePtr head = NULL;
StockNodePtr *next = &head; // points to the next pointer to assign.
while(not finished)
{
    StockNodePtr newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));

    // ...
    // set all your fields.
    //

    // whatever pointer `next` points to gets the new node. on an
    //  initial list it will be the `head` pointer. on a subsequent
    //  node it will be the `nextStock` pointer of the last-node-added.
    *next = newNode;

    // now just set the new next-pointer-to-populate to be the `nextStock`
    //  pointer of the node we just added.
    next = &newNode->nextStock;
}

// terminate the last node
*next = NULL;
```

The `next` pointer in the previous code always holds the *address* of the next pointer to fill. Initially it is populated with the *address* of the `head` pointer variable. When the loop finishes, whatever pointer `next` is pointing to needs to be set to NULL to terminate the list. Note: you need not set `newNode->nextStock = NULL;` when setting your fields. Either the next iteration of the loop will set it for you (to the next node) or the `*next = NULL;` after the loop will set it to NULL if it was the last node added.

---

I would dive into the usages of `strtok()` and all those pointers, but I'm late for dinner and my better half is calling. I hope this is at least somewhat helpful. Good luck, and have a dynamite day.

Comment: Oh, dear... what a colossal error on my part.  Works fine now, you nailed it.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, "strlen" returns the length of the string but doesn't include the terminating \0. Be sure to append that when copying your strings, else later calls operating on your tokenized strings may not terminate correctly.

Comment: one more thing to add... Not a good coding practice to use keywords as variable names. In this case, 'new' has been used as a variable name.